# Eureka lib in swift: How can I loop rows?

Tags: swift, uitableview, for-loop, rows, eureka-forms

Maybe it's a useless question, but I'm trying to make a "for loop" with labelRow, but it don't do what I want.

I want the same things as the example project of Eureka with SegmentedRow, but in segment I want to do a loop for rows.

Can someone guide me?

This is what I tried in view did load:

```
 self.form = Section()
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
            $0.options = ["Passées", "En cours", "Futures"]
            $0.value = "En cours"
        }
        
        +++ Section(){
            $0.tag = "past_s"
            $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Passées'" // .Predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$segments != 'Sport'"))
    }
    
    for it in self.past {
        self.form.last! <<< TextRow() { row in
            row.title = "Which is your favourite soccer player?"
        }
    }
    
    self.form +++= Section(){
        $0.tag = "waiting_s"
        $0.hidden = "$segments != 'En cours'"
    }
    
    for it in self.waiting {
        self.form.last! <<< TextRow() { row in
            row.title = "Which is your favourite soccer player?"
        }
    }
    
    self.form +++= Section(){
        $0.tag = "futur_s"
        $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Futures'"
    }
    
    for it in self.future {
        self.form.last! <<< TextRow() { row in
            row.title = "Which is your favourite soccer player?"
        }
    }
```

and thats what i'm waiting :)

```
self.form = Section()
    <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
        $0.options = ["Passées", "En cours", "Futures"]
        $0.value = "En cours"
    }
    
    +++ Section(){
        $0.tag = "past_s"
        $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Passées'" // .Predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$segments != 'Sport'"))
    }
    
    <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "1"
    }
    
    <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "temp"
    }
    
    +++ Section(){
        $0.tag = "waiting_s"
        $0.hidden = "$segments != 'En cours'"
    }
    
    <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "2"
    }
    
    <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "temp"
    }
    
    +++ Section(){
        $0.tag = "futur_s"
        $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Futures'"
    }
    
    <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "3"
    }
    
    <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "temp"
}
```

I've tried that too (and a lot of others ways):

```
form +++ Section()
form.last! <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
    $0.options = ["Passées", "En cours", "Futures"]
    $0.value = "En cours"
}

form +++= Section(){
    $0.tag = "past_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Passées'"
}

for past in self.past {
    form.last! <<< LabelRow() { row in
        row.title = "1"
    }
}
```

and try this too :

```
form = Section()
    <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
        $0.options = ["Passées", "En cours", "Futures"]
        $0.value = "En cours"
}

form +++ self.pastSection!
form +++ self.waitingSection!
form +++ self.futurSection!

self.pastSection = Section("past_s") {
    $0.tag = "past_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Passées'"
}

self.waitingSection = Section("waiting_s") {
    $0.tag = "waiting_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'En cours'"
}

self.futurSection = Section("futur_s") {
    $0.tag = "futur_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Futures'"
}

for past in self.past {
    self.pastSection!
        <<< LabelRow() {
            $0.title = "test"
    }
}

for waiting in self.waiting {
    self.waitingSection!
        <<< LabelRow() {
            $0.title = "test"
    }
}

for futur in self.future {
    self.futurSection!
        <<< LabelRow() {
            $0.title = "test"
    }
}

form +++ self.pastSection!
form +++ self.waitingSection!
form +++ self.futurSection!
```

But I got an error like this:

[image: photo of error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer!

```
form.delegate = nil
form.removeAll()

form +++= Section("DuplicateCounter") { row in row.tag = "DuplicateCounter" }

    <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
        $0.options = ["Passées", "En cours", "Futures"]
        $0.value = "En cours"
}

self.pastSection = Section("past_s") {
    $0.tag = "past_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Passées'"
}

self.waitingSection = Section("waiting_s") {
    $0.tag = "waiting_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'En cours'"
}

self.futurSection = Section("futur_s") {
    $0.tag = "futur_s"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Futures'"
}

form +++ self.pastSection!
form +++ self.waitingSection!
form +++ self.futurSection!

for past in self.past {
    self.pastSection!
        <<< LabelRow("\(past.id)") {
            $0.title = "test"
    }
}

for waiting in self.waiting {
    self.waitingSection!
        <<< LabelRow("\(waiting.id)") {
            $0.title = "test"
    }
}

for futur in self.future {
    self.futurSection!
        <<< LabelRow("\(futur.id)") {
            $0.title = "test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This my way to do it using an Json file and loop entries -->

```
 do {

        if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "linhas_fretados", withExtension: "json") {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)

            let json = JSON(data: data)
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

                let inserir_fretado = Linhas_Fretado(
                    linha: subJson["Linha"].stringValue,
                    hora_saida_sa: subJson["Campus Santo André Partida"].stringValue,
                    hora_saida_sbc: subJson["Campus São Bernardo Partida"].stringValue,
                    hora_saida_tmnl: subJson["Terminal Leste"].stringValue)


                if(subJson["Campus Santo André Partida"] != ""){
                    self.Saida_SA.append(inserir_fretado)
                }

                if(subJson["Terminal Leste"] != ""){
                    self.Saida_TMNL.append(inserir_fretado)
                }

                if(subJson["Campus São Bernardo Partida"] != ""){
                    self.Saida_SBC.append(inserir_fretado)
                }
            }
        } else {}
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    let formulario =  form
        formulario +++ Section("Onde Voce está?:")
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
            $0.options = ["SA", "TERMINAL", "SBC"]
            $0.value = "SA"
        }

//#################### ONIBUS SAINDO DE SSANTOS ANDRE MANO #############
        formulario +++ Section("Saindo de SA"){
            $0.tag = "SA_s"
            $0.hidden = "$segments != 'SA'"
        }


    var i = 0
    while i <= (Saida_SA.count-1) {
        form.sectionBy(tag: "SA_s")! <<< TextRow() { $0.title = "Linha \(self.Saida_SA[i].linha)" ; $0.value = self.Saida_SA[i].hora_saida_sa ; $0.disabled = true }
        i = i + 1
    }


//#################### ONIBUS SAINDO DO TERMINALLLLOUAOOOASOASOA #############
    formulario +++ Section(){
        $0.tag = "TERMINAL_s"
        $0.hidden = "$segments != 'TERMINAL'"
    }

    var a = 0
    while a <= (Saida_SA.count-1) {
         form.sectionBy(tag: "TERMINAL_s")! <<< TextRow() { $0.title = "Linha \(self.Saida_TMNL[a].linha)" ; $0.value = self.Saida_TMNL[a].hora_saida_tmnl ; $0.disabled = true }
        a = a + 1
    }


  //#################### ONIBUS SAINDO DE SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO #############
        formulario +++ Section(){
            $0.tag = "SBC_s"
            $0.hidden = "$segments != 'SBC'"
        }

    var i2 = 0
    while i2 <= (Saida_SA.count-1) {
         form.sectionBy(tag: "SBC_s")! <<< TextRow() { $0.title = "Linha \(self.Saida_SBC[i2].linha)" ; $0.value = self.Saida_SBC[i2].hora_saida_sbc ; $0.disabled = true }
        i2 = i2 + 1
    }
```

I lost a lot of time creating this and search around the internet, I does not find something else like this, so I hope you enjoy bro.

Comment: Hey, maybe you should put it in english instead, just for, you know, the global understanding.
And maybe it's not enough generic, like without the json in your code, i mean, this is not really the subject in what i talked before. 
(ps: don't you prefer in swift to use loop for instead of while ?)
Still thanks for your answer. :)